# Resultado Null Vindo em query

Tags: sql-server, query

Bom dia,

Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês, tenho uma query em meu sistema está com um problema, ela trás 4 resultados, só que 1 desses 4 está vindo com valor nulo. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou postar a minha query abaixo

```
SELECT Title, SUM(Count) AS Count
FROM (
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND EstadoId = Meddoc1 AND EstadoId = Meddoc2 AND EstadoId = Meddoc3 THEN
            'Sem deslocamento'
            ELSE CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId = Meddoc1 OR EstadoId = Meddoc2 OR EstadoId = Meddoc3) THEN
            'Fora de domicílio do autor'
            ELSE CASE WHEN EstadoId <> EstadoIdAutor OR (EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId <> Meddoc1 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc2 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc3)) THEN
            'Mais de um deslocamento'
            END
            END
    END AS Title,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM jud_Processos
    WHERE Status = 1 AND Trancado = 1
    GROUP BY EstadoId, EstadoIdAutor, Meddoc1, Meddoc2, Meddoc3
) Sub
GROUP BY Title
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Aonde está **NULL** vir como **Outros**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você só precisa adicionar o `ELSE` no seu `CASE`:

```
SELECT title,
       SUM(count) AS count
  FROM (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN estadoid = estadoidautor
                      AND estadoid = meddoc1
                      AND estadoid = meddoc2
                      AND estadoid = meddoc3 THEN 'Sem deslocamento'
                 WHEN estadoid = estadoidautor
                      AND (estadoid = meddoc1
                       OR estadoid = meddoc2
                       OR estadoid = meddoc3) THEN 'Fora de domicílio do autor'
                 WHEN estadoid <> estadoidautor
                      OR (estadoid = estadoidautor
                      AND (estadoid <> meddoc1
                      AND estadoid <> meddoc2
                      AND estadoid <> meddoc3)) THEN 'Mais de um deslocamento'
                 ELSE 'Outros'
               END AS title,
               COUNT(*) AS count
          FROM jud_processos
         WHERE status = 1
           AND trancado = 1
         GROUP BY estadoid,
                  estadoidautor,
                  meddoc1,
                  meddoc2,
                  meddoc3) sub
 GROUP BY title
```

Observação: Você só precisa de um `CASE` na sua `query`.

Comment: Cara funcionou muito obrigado, não consigo qualificar como correto agora, mais assim que liberar eu qualifico!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o coalesce

```
SELECT COALESCE(Title,'OUTROS'), SUM(Count) AS Count
FROM (
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND EstadoId = Meddoc1 AND EstadoId = Meddoc2 AND EstadoId = Meddoc3 THEN
            'Sem deslocamento'
            ELSE CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId = Meddoc1 OR EstadoId = Meddoc2 OR EstadoId = Meddoc3) THEN
            'Fora de domicílio do autor'
            ELSE CASE WHEN EstadoId <> EstadoIdAutor OR (EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId <> Meddoc1 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc2 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc3)) THEN
            'Mais de um deslocamento'
            END
            END
    END AS Title,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM jud_Processos
    WHERE Status = 1 AND Trancado = 1
    GROUP BY EstadoId, EstadoIdAutor, Meddoc1, Meddoc2, Meddoc3
) Sub
GROUP BY Title
```

Comment: Este funcionou também amigo, muito obrigado é muito bom ter outros exemplos.

Comment: que bom! :). Assim você pode escolher o mais legível para você e mais fácil.